# Finding closed form expression for the roots of $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^K \frac{\alpha_i \gamma_i \sin(x-\theta_i)}{1+\gamma_i[1+\cos(x-\theta_i) ]}$

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, roots

Let us define function  $f:R \rightarrow R$ as follows:

\begin{align}
f(x)\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^K  \frac{\alpha_i \gamma_i \sin(x-\theta_i)}{1+\gamma_i[1+\cos(x-\theta_i) ]},
\end{align}
where anything except $x$ is a given parameter. I am trying to find the closed form solutions of $f(x)=0$. Does anybody know how to do that? If it is not possible to find a closed form solution, can we say something about the number of solutions? Is there finite number of solutions?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**: Since $f(x)$ is periodic, I am only interested in finding the solutions located in the interval $[0~2\pi]$.

**Edit 2**: Is there a way to find every solution in $[0~2\pi]$ numerically?

Comment: By periodicity of the trig functions, if there are any solutions, there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 2):

Except in the case $K=1$, I do not see a way to obtain a closed form solution. As for the number of solutions, observe that (here I assume that $\gamma_i>-1$, so that the denominators never vanish)
$$
f(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}\,\sum_{i=1}^K\log\bigl(1+\gamma_i(1+\cos(x-\theta_i))\bigr).
$$
The roots of $f$ are precisely the critical points of  $\sum_{i=1}^K\log\bigl(1+\gamma_i(1+\cos(x-\theta_i))\bigr)$. Since this is a smooth function of period $2\pi$, it attains its maximum and minimum on any interval of length $2\,\pi$, so that $f$ has at least two roots on every interval of length $2\,\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. Can we say anything about the maximum number of solutions in each period of length $2\pi$? Moreover, If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions, can we find a lower bound for $x_1$-$x_2$?

Comment: I do not see any simple argument that would answer those questions. My guess is that there could be an upper bound on the number of solutions in terms of $K$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to find every solution in
[0, 2π] numerically?

Comment: First locate the roots; you can do this drawing the graph of $f$ with software. Then use a numerical method, like bisection or Newton.